# angles in D:M:S format in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel file using pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',index_col='Sl.No') with values as below

```
Sl.No  Actual
69.1   -45:22:13
70.0   5.9657
71.1   45:01:37
71.2   45:01:09
71.3   -44:59:01
```

in the resultant dataframe, Sl.No 69.1 and 71.3 are being read as string, Sl.No 70.0 as float, 71.1 and 72.2 as 1899-12-31 21:00:58 and 1899-12-31 21:00:29. I want to read these as strings.

How do I do this

excel file exported as cvs

Sl.No  Actual,
69.1,-45:22:13
70,5.9657
71.1,45:01:37
71.2,45:01:09
71.3,-44:59:01

Comment: the issue likely originates in excel, can you export from excel as CSV and provide the content in your question?

Comment: In excel Sl.No 69.1 and 71.3 are is stored as text. 71.1 and 71.2 are formatted as time with a format of [H]:MM:SS. I am opening the file in libreoffice to see the cell format

Comment: you need to set the format as raw string in excel/libreoffice before you do anything in python

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have hundreds of these files to process. I don't have any control over these files. Is there any way to parse all values as strings while reading excel file?